# Add watermark text on mkv video using ffmpeg windows version

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark

I want to add a watermark text to an `.mkv` video using `ffmpeg` on Windows. I want the watermark to be like a subtitle that starts on the second minute and lasts for 30 seconds and says: "copyright to mysite.com".

I tried `mkvmerge` to add a subtitle but it can be easily deleted by others, so now I'm relying on `ffmpeg` to do this for me. Can anyone help me with the process?

I want the watermark to be actually on the video so it can't be deleted using `mkvmerge`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`subtitles`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) or [`drawtext`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) filters to place text on video, but as with any video filter both methods **require the video to be re-encoded**.

## `subtitles` filter

- Accepts a subtitles file in the ASS or SRT formats. These can be easily made with [aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/), or even via a text editor.
- This filter will produce *hardsubs* which are subtitles that become part of the video. They can not be toggled on or off.
- The timing is controlled by the subtitles file.
- ASS subtitles should allow fancier effects than SRT subtitles or usage of the `drawtext` filter.

#### Example

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -map 0 -vf subtitles=subs.ass -c copy -c:v libx264 out.mkv
```

- This example will override the default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior and map all streams from the input with `-map 0`.
- All streams will be [stream copied](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) except for the video stream(s) which will be re-encoded.
- The filter can also refer to an existing subtitles stream within the input file, such as `subtitles=video.mkv` or `subtitles=video.mkv:si=1`.

## `drawtext` filter

This filter will draw text onto the video. Usually used for a simple word or sentence. The time it is displayed can be controlled with the [`enable` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing).

#### Example

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -map 0 -vf "drawtext=enable='between(t,120,150)':fontsize=20: \
font=Sans:text='© mysite.com':x=w-tw-10:y=h-th-10" -c copy -c:v libx264 out.mkv
```

- This example will place the text in the lower right corner with a padding of 10 pixels.
- If your `ffmpeg` build does not support fontconfig, then you will have to use the `fontfile` option instead of `font` and provide the full path the the font file.

## Also see

- [`subtitles` filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles)
- [`drawtext` filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)
- [Zeranoe FFmpeg Builds for Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com)